# Get multiple mobile phone numbers via microsoft graph api from outlook.com contact

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to read all contact data from my outlook.com account into my app via

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?$top=10000
```

At first glance, this seems to work well, but later I noticed this:
For contacts with multiple mobile phone numbers, Microsoft only sends the first mobile phone number.

In `v1.0` api version of graph, there is simply no field for a second mobile phone number, but in beta api each [contact](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/contact#properties) has the property `phones`, which is a collection of objects of [phone resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/phone). Therefore it should be possible to get multiple mobile phone numbers.

Is this a bug in the API or am I doing something wrong? Is there a different API, that provides all contact data?

EDIT:

As requested per comment: I really mean multiple mobile phone numbers:
[image: outlook.com with multiple mobile phones]

Comment: Can you confirm that you mean multiple mobile numbers specifically and not phone numbers in general?  If so, I'm not sure that's supported. 
 When I tried to add multiple mobile numbers via Graph to a single contact I got the error :
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "The multi-value property Phones has too many entries of the following type: of type: contacts:PhoneNumber:MobilePhone. The maximum number allowed is 1.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "2017-12-29T20:07:46"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like multiple mobile phone numbers isn't supported by Graph. In v1.0 API, each contact has a `mobilePhone` string property (not an array).  In beta Graph API, when you try adding multiple mobile phone numbers to a contact you get the following error:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts/{contact-id}
{
    "phones": [
        { "number": "1234567891", type: "home"},
        { "number": "9876543210", type: "mobile"},
        { "number": "4564564562", type: "mobile"}, // second mobile number
     ]
}


// Response

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "The multi-value property Phones has too many entries of the following type: of type: contacts:PhoneNumber:MobilePhone. The maximum number allowed is 1.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "578d85ba-e467-47a4-8cc1-5671fde4a83f",
            "date": "2017-12-29T20:07:46"
        }
    }
}
```

However, you can get all phone numbers for all contacts in one call when contacts have different types of numbers - home, mobile, etc.  I just tested this with an outlook.com account and here are the API calls to set multiple phone numbers on a contact and get them all in one API call.

I found a random contact to test with, copied their ID and made a `PATCH` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts/[contact-id]`.

Patch body:

```
{
  "phones": [
     { "number": "1234567891", type: "home"},
     { "number": "9876543210", type: "mobile"},
   ]
}
```

To confirm the phones were in fact updated, I sent a request to `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts/[contact-id]/phones` and the two phone numbers were returned in the JSON response.

Sending this same request to the `v1.0` endpoint won't work since there isn't a phones property on a contact. However, you can still get this data in v1.0 since it's just split across multiple fields.

[image]

It looks like sending a request to `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?$select=phones` returns phones for all users.

[image]

The beta API is subject to change so we don't recommend building production applications that depend on the this endpoint. Please keep an eye on the [public changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog) for when this will move to v1.0.

If you would like to see support for multiple mobile phones in Graph API, please post on our [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/filters/top?category_id=101632).

Comment: Thanks!! Is there any other api to get all mobile phone numbers?

Comment: You can try GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people - Retrieve a collection of person objects ordered by their relevance to the user, which is determined by the user's communication and collaboration patterns, and business relationships. It has all phones. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http